# Compare stocked string and hard written string with If Statement

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio

I want to compare two strings :

- one is stocked in a variable;
- the other is written in the IDE.

I want to compare them with `if-statement`, but it doesn't work.
This is the line I use :

```
Command | Target           | Value |<br>
if      | ${i}=="mystring" |       |
```

This statement always enter in the "success" case even when the strings are differents and I can't find any doc about Katalon on the web.

Comment: tag your binding language for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try -

```
verifyEval | ${i}=="mystring"  | true
```

It shall return true if both the strings are same else false.